# What will be the query to fetch the order id of a particular order from a database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

What will be the query to fetch the Goal_id of  a particular Goal_name from a database Imagine one column is of Goal_id and another column is of Goal_name[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugCji.png) .I want it in below format(native query)

```
@Query("Select a from UserEntity a where a.userId= :userId")    
List<UserEntity> getUserById(@Param("userId") String userId);
```

I want to use this in spring boot where i will get a order number from UI and i want to fetch the corresponding order id of that order number

Comment: Order model please?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to this. 
The details might vary depending on the exact design of your entities and things like if you expect 1, 0-1 or N results and if you want a `List` or a `Set`.

```
@Query("SELECT a.goalId FROM UserEntity a where a.goalName = :name")
List<Long> getIdsForName(String name)
```

Answer (score 1):

your return response must be like UserEntity.getUserNumber() if you have userNumber attribute.